# @AfterMethod is called twice in onConfigurationSuccess Method. Bug in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

I have a listener class, which implements IResultListener. In that class I implement the onConfigurationSuccess Method, todo something after the test method. But the @AfterMethod annotated method is called twice after the same test method. I check this with a console output:

```
public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult itr) {
    if (itr.getMethod().isAfterMethodConfiguration()) {
        System.out.println("Aftermethod: " + itr.getMethod().getMethodName());
        Object[] parameters = itr.getParameters();
        ITestResult originalResult = (ITestResult) parameters[0];
        System.out.println("Testmethod: " + originalResult.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Does anyone has the same problem? I have only one @AfterMethod method and the testmethod runs one time. Is this a bug in testng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used testng version 6.3.1 and the problem only appears here. In actual version 6.5.2 it works fine.